# See what functions are currently setInterval'd

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

How can I see what functions are currently `setInterval`ed or `setTimeout`ed in javascript?

Comment: if you are calling `setINterval` and `setTimeout` yourself you could save all functions to an array?

Comment: There's no API for examining/querying the timers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats not possible. You have to keep the id's which are returned by setInterval oder setTimeout. When keeping the id's you can also keep the functions name in which the interval or timeout is set. :-)

So you can build a list of all timeouts and intervals.

Then you can loop through this array and produce a list.

a little example:

```
var timeoutArray;

var oldSetTimeout = setTimeout;

setTimeout = function(){
    timeoutArray.push(oldSetTimeout(your_function, your_timeout));
}
```